# Is Ubuntu 14 more stable than Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04

I am currently using Ubuntu 12.04 for my workstation with 32 cores. I use it to run molecular dynamics simulation using 16 cores simultaneously. Due to the nature of the computation, I need to run it for days without stop. My workstation often crashes with unknown reason after I run a job of this type for a day or two. Will this instability be gone if I upgrade to Ubuntu 14?

Comment: It may be more stable for some, and less for others. It's hard to be sure, without knowing the causes.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu may not be your best bet for Linux distro. While it is stable, it's not ultra stable like you seem to need. Since you're still on 12.04 it also doesn't seem like you need to be on the cutting edge. I would recommend Debian, which is very stable and somewhat familiar to Ubuntu users since Ubuntu is based on it.